# Floating point representation and mantissa

Tags: numbers

So there was this question on a Programming fundamentals past paper based on the unit number bases. I'm putting it down here

> How will the number 45612.3789 be represented in a floating point
>   notation which has a five digit mantissa, the decimal point after the
>   second digit from left and 10 as the base for the exponent?

From what I can understand the answer should be 45.61237x10^3. Since the floating point part of the number is called the mantissa.

Is it the answer? I don't see a relation between the question and number bases and I'm kinda confused. If it is not the answer, what is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unanswerable without knowing the intended radix, which is implied but not stated as 10 by the use of the phrase 'decimal point'.

Comment: The question is word to word from the question paper itself. So I guess we have to assume that it is 10??

Comment: You could do that but I would state it clearly as an assumption that you're making because it was omitted from the question. The answer in binary would be completely different. Worthy of a complaint really.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.